# Get the list from list of object using Linq dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have an app with a list of objects. I want to create multiple lists from that single list, based on one of the parameters, dynamically.

I have searched but could not find how to make it work exactly. Here are the details.

I have a class `ProductDetails` with these properties:

```
    public class ProductItem
    {
        public string StoreId { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
```

The current list is filled like this:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>() {
     new Item() { ProductName = Pen, StoreId = 1, StoreName = Test },
     new Item() { ProductName = Pen, StoreId = 2, StoreName = Test2 },
     new Item() { ProductName = Pen, StoreId = 2, StoreName = Test2 },
     new Item() { ProductName = Pen, StoreId = 1, StoreName = Test }
};
```

My requirement is to create lists which have distinct store names.

In my example, I should get 2 lists as there are two unique store names in the sample data.

How can I write a Linq query to prepare dynamic lists from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to achieve this by grouping the items based on the unique StoreName, I think the following code should work for you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class ProductItem
{
    public string StoreId { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<ProductItem> items = new List<ProductItem>(){
            new ProductItem(){ ProductName = "Pen", StoreId = "1", StoreName = "Test"},
            new ProductItem(){ ProductName = "Pen", StoreId = "2", StoreName = "Test2"},
            new ProductItem(){ ProductName = "Pen", StoreId = "2", StoreName = "Test2"},
            new ProductItem(){ ProductName = "Pen", StoreId = "1", StoreName = "Test"}
        };

        // LINQ query to group by StoreName
        var groupedLists = items.GroupBy(item => item.StoreName)
                                .Select(group => group.ToList())
                                .ToList();

        // Displaying the results
        foreach (var groupedList in groupedLists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"List for StoreName: {groupedList.First().StoreName}");
            foreach (var item in groupedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  ProductName: {item.ProductName}, StoreId: {item.StoreId}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `ToList` what is it gaining you?

Comment: You are right, it is redundant in this case. But to be honest I provided a solution, not the optimized one. There could be several other issues that I can find in my own code where there is some hope for improvement.

Comment: Thanks @Zohair: It worked like a charm... I made small modifications.

Comment: Glad to know that :)